# What's included in Migration Assistant's "Other Files & Folders"?

Tags: migration-assistant

Migration Assistant offers a top level checkbox for "Other Files & Folders".

[image: macOS Migration Assistant]

It's not clear what's included in this item. Maybe stuff from `/usr/`? There must be more to it than that, since there is a lot more data listed by Migration Assistant than I can find in there.

What filesystem paths correspond to this "Other Files & Folders" item?

Comment: Were you able to get the answer?